# sql + visual studio/(login/registration System) How to make a user control hold data

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

The application is a store, it's a windows form application, where the user can login/register, buy and sell it's products, with items based per tags.

The thing is, I want to know if there is a way to make a user control hold the data inserted on him, and then, only when the process of registration is over, let it send to the database.

The idea is to have only one windows form for Registration, inside it, two user controls, since I don't want the app to take much space on the screen.

Should I make the user control send the data to the button that finish the registration and then when i click on him he releases to the database? Is there a way to do this?

*This question stayed with me after i finished my course. We had to do a project on the final of the course using both sql and visual studios, we weren't able to finish it the way we wanted.

It bugged me, so I'm trying to do it now.
*

Comment: Is it Windows forms application or web application? Can you share whatever code you have tried?

Comment: It's a windows forms application, unfortunately i only have the unfinished version of my project on my pc, and this version is the one we gave up and maded only one forms with all the data on it ( https://imgur.com/zSgJXA5 ) since the two steps registration did not work, we deleted it. i'm trying to do it from zero. but i want to know if is possible to make the user control to send the data to a button.

Comment: You may create a global DataSet variable and appropriate DataTable objects and all data related information keep in there. After you decide it is time to persist this to some database there are several ways how you can achieve this.